# evaluate and assign method value in a succinct way

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in Ruby to assign a value which is also used for evaluating in a succinct way, that is, without storing the result of the method (in the case below) before evaluating and assigning it?

```
def expensive_operation
...
end

ary = []
ary << expensive_operation unless expensive_operation.nil?
```

Comment: How are you going to know if an expensive operation is going to do something unless you do it? If you do it and don't store the value won't you have to do it again if you want the value? You can do a preflight check to make sure the inputs to that operation are available and sensible and will result in a usable result.  [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is where we store values that might need to be computed many times, helping to reduce the system load, however it'll still have to be computed at least once.

Comment: I would argue it depends on what the `expensive_opention` calculates and how it the algorithm works. I can think of situations in which it it easy to tell that the algorithm cannot return a valid result, but it would still be hard to tell the exact result when it is possible. For example, you might be able to tell that some pre-conditions not meet, before trying to calculate the `expensive_operation`. Can you tell us more about the operation?

Comment: please at least try and understand the question before answering it, and if you don't, ask me to clarify. I never say that we do not need to calculate the result. Of course we need to calculate the result, I'm just asking if there is some syntactic sugar in Ruby that allows you to compute, evaluate and then assign i a succinct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a better way to write something like:

```
ary = []
result = expensive_operation
ary << result unless result.nil?
```

You can use:

```
ary = [expensive_operation].compact
```

or:

```
ary = []
ary += [expensive_operation].compact
```

The `compact` method will remove all `nil` values from an array.

Or if you want to check against something else, you could use `reject`:

```
ary = [expensive_operation].reject { |e| e == '' }
```

This will remove any elements for which the block returns `true`.

If this is actually more readable depends on the surround code...

If "without storing the result of the method" you mean "without actually running the expensive operation", then no, this is not really possible... It's like saying "can I know what the result of 2 + 2 is without actually calculating 2 + 2"?

Comment: Thanks, you understood me correctly. The only reason I was asking is that there is usually many different ways of accomplishing the same thing in Ruby so I was just interested in alternative methods. storing does not mean computing :)